# Reading data from a SharedObject file directly

Tags: actionscript-3, decode, shared-objects

I am attempting to read the data directly from a SharedObject (.sol) file in as3. I've been able to extract the header information :

```
// HEADER BYTES
var header1:int = stream.readShort();

// LENGTH
var length:int = header1 & 0x3f;
if (length == 0x3f)
    length = stream.readInt();


// FILETYPE - should be "TCSO"
var sig:String = stream.readUTFBytes( 4 );

// PAD: Unused, 6 bytes long 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
var pad:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
stream.readBytes( pad, 0, 6 );

// NAME
//   2 byte short length
var nameLength:int = stream.readUnsignedShort();
var name:String = stream.readUTFBytes( nameLength );

var amfVersion:int = stream.readInt();
```

But I am having troubles interpreting the data that follows:

```
var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
stream.readBytes( data );
```

I was under the belief it was stored as AMF data and hence the ByteArray.readObject function should correctly decode it:

```
var sharedObjectData:Object = data.readObject();
```

However this fails with all of my test objects with a Range Error.

Does anyone know the format of the data in a SharedObject or how to decode it?

---

REASON: I am doing this because we have an app deployed and accidentally changed the name of the swf which made the SharedObject inaccessible using the SharedObject class.

ie. SharedObject in app_new.swf can't read `#SharedObjects/app.swf/objectname.sol`

So need to parse the `sol` SharedObject file using direct File access.

Comment: Please explain what's the point of it? Well, besides the reading it as a proof of concept.

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: Why don't you just relocate the sol to where the SWF expects it to be?

Comment: Well yes I could copy the new one out of the way, move the old one, read it , to memory, copy the old one back and read it to memory and then merge and create a new one, but was hoping to simplify the merge and didn't think it would be that hard to read the file?

Comment: If so, just have a temp name for your old-new file and read them both, then merge, then purge old SO storage, and let it be. By reading I mean opening a SO with the correct name.

Comment: Unfortunately SharedObject fails if the name doesn't match, the name is used in the file (see above) and as the filename so you can't just use a temp name.

Comment: Did you consider googling some third-party implementation (with source code available)? Like http://blog.sephiroth.it/projects/shared-object-reader/ - there's PHP implementation at the bottom.

Comment: I've ended up writing my own as3 parser using hints from some of the other language implementations available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use sharedObjects (never needed them) so I can only advise about bytes. Anytime you get "out of range/bounds" error it can be fixed with checking & correcting the byte array's `.position`.

In your case, first trace position and length of `data` to be sure there is enough data in front (from current position) to read an `Object` out of those remaining bytes.

Other options to try for solving *"Out of range"* error: (use `.writeBytes` instead of `.readBytes`)

```
var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

//or replace "stream.position" with offset value where you think "Object" data begins
data.writeBytes( stream, stream.position, stream.bytesAvailable );

data.position = 0; //reset before reading
var sharedObjectData:Object = data.readObject();
```

Also look at [**`Inflate`**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#inflate()) and [**`Uncompress`**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#uncompress()) just incase data must be expanded before usage.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but unfortunately that's not the issue, I had correctly positioned the data position at the start of the AMF data but the range error occurs from within the readObject() call. I've ended up writing my own parser which is working correctly now.